# Java won't respond to my input

Tags: java

I'm budding into java and I've been trying to write this basic program where it asks you a yes or no question, you give it an answer and then it does something based off that answer. currently my code is this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String args[])

{
    Scanner inputvar = new Scanner (System.in);
    String yes, no;
    System.out.println("Enter yes or no");
    yes = inputvar.nextLine();
    no = inputvar.nextLine();

    if (inputvar.equals(yes))
    {
    System.out.println("You said yes!");
    }

    else if (inputvar.equals(no)){
        System.out.println("You said no");
    }

  }
}
```

I don't get any errors when compiling but when I run the program It doesn't reply when I put anything in. It allows me to enter two lines of text then it terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code yes, no variables are not correct, you invoke `nextLine()` twice in your code, that's why you are asked to enter inputs twice.

```
yes = inputvar.nextLine();
no = inputvar.nextLine();
```

`inputvar` is a `Scanner` instance, not a `String` object, you cannot try 
`inputvar.equals(yes)`

You should only define:

```
 String myInput = inputvar.nextLine();
```

and checks

```
if (myInput.equals("yes")){
//do some stuff
}else if(myInput.equals("no")){
//do other stuff
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood, keep `Scanner inputvar`, remove String variables `yes` and `no`, just create one `String myInput`, and assigne `inputvar.nextLine()` to myInput, then in your `if-else`, use String `myInput` to compare with "yes" "no"

Comment: Sorry, still figuring this all out. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner inputvar = new Scanner (System.in);
String yes, no;
System.out.println("Enter yes or no");
yes = inputvar.nextLine();  // You enter the first line
no = inputvar.nextLine();   // You enter the second line

if (inputvar.equals(yes))   // You try to compare an instance of 
                            // Scanner with the firstline (not equal)
{
System.out.println("You said yes!");
}

else if (inputvar.equals(no)){    // You try to compare an instance of 
                                  // Scanner with the firstline (not equal)
    System.out.println("You said no");
}
// You terminate the program
```

You should do something like:

```
String yes = "yes";
String no = "no";

String input = inputvar.nextLine();

if(yes.equals(input)) { [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this

```
Scanner inputvar = new Scanner (System.in);
String input;
System.out.println("Enter yes or no");
input = inputvar.nextLine();


if (input.equals(yes))
{
System.out.println("You said yes!");
}

else if (input.equals(no)){
    System.out.println("You said no");
}
```

Hope this helps and best of luck.